# How do you redirect from an app, to a webpage?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating an app for the Iphone and i'm using Cocos2d.

As part of the help menu, i want to redirect the user to a site when they click a link. Is it possible to do in cocos2d?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)